# how to handle cloned multiple file uploads fields in php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

i have multiple clone file upload fields

```
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="images" name="muti_files[]" multiple="multiple" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="images" name="muti_files[]" multiple="multiple" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="file" id="images" name="muti_files[]" multiple="multiple" required>
    </div>
</div>
```

and i submit this through jQuery to my php file

```
jQuery("#p_upload_form").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let dataToSend = [];
    var gattering =[] ;
    var serializedData =new FormData(this);
    });
    request = jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://staging.toycycle.co/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/process_category.php",
        type: "post",
        data:  serializedData,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false, 
    });
    
    request.done(function (data){
        
        console.log("server side", data);
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
    });

    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        
        console.error(
            "The following error occurred: "+
            textStatus, errorThrown
        );
    });
});
```

now in php I handle this like so,

```
if (!empty($_FILES['muti_files'][$i])) {
    $files = $_FILES['muti_files'][$i];
    echo "<pre>" . print_r($files, true) . "</pre>";
    foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
        if ($files['name'][$key]) {
            $file = array(
                'name' => $files['name'][$key],
                'type' => $files['type'][$key],
                'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
                'error' => $files['error'][$key],
                'size' => $files['size'][$key]
            );
        }
        $_FILES = array(
            "muti_files" => $file
        );

        $i = 1;
        foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
            if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) __return_false();
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
            $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);
            $vv .= $attachment_id . ",";
            $i++;
        }
        if ($key === array_key_first($files['name'])) {
            //echo "<pre>" .print_r($attachment_id , true). "</pre>";
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);
            unset($vv);
        } else {
            update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_image_gallery', $vv);
        }
        array_push($attachment_id_array, $attachment_id);
    }
}
```

Now this solution works for single multiple files upload field.In current situation all images are assigned to on post.
But i want to submit all the cloned fields data to php so they can b attached to there respective post
how can I achieve this ?